# Changing og tag based on url params

Tags: html, linkedin-api

this is the parameter I add in my header that let me show a thumbnail in my linkedin messages

```
<meta property="og:image" content="imageurl">
```

I would like this image to be dynamic : show different page thumbnail on linkedin messages, by adding query parameters in my url

For example those 2 urls

```
website/?param=1
website/?param=2
```

Should modify my og:image property like this

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can do it server side.  Are you using any server-side language such as PHP ?

Comment: Yes server side is a good idea. But is it possible in javascript on a simple html page?

Comment: I doubt it.  The page has to load first before javascript will run.  By then linkedin would have grabbed the original image.  I would say, dont be afraid of multiple pages, just make new ones.

Answer (score -1):

Edit this doesn't work:

```
<script>  var link = document.createElement('meta');  link.setAttribute('property', 'og:image');  link.content = imageurl;  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you do generate the meta tags, but the page has already been loaded before the tags are generated. This won't work. Consider using server-side programming instead.

Comment: Yes you are right it doesn't work you have to do it sever side